# Where can I rent a computer monitor for two weeks in Hyderabad (Telangana, India)?

Tags: india, rental, hyderabad

Where can I rent a computer monitor for around two weeks in Hyderabad (Telangana, India)?

The computer monitors on http://www.amazon.in/ and http://www.olx.in/ are more expensive than I'm used to, so I'm looking to rent them since I just need them for ~2 weeks. I'm looking for average sized computer monitors, i.e. around 24 to 27 inches.

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- http://qr.ae/TUNGSV
- https://redd.it/9913rb

Comment: Is there a travel connection here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because does not seem to be related to travel

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk yes when one travels, one needs temporary basic equipment.

Comment: @Newton [What is our stance on "where can I rent X in location Y" questions?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4798/1810)

Comment: Please close voters, do realize that people who travel for work often need things for work which they might not need as tourists. This is a travel question as much as one about a hotel or a car rental.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vikas Anthati (http://qr.ae/TUNGSV) referred to me to https://www.sabrentkaro.com, where one can rent monitors: https://www.sabrentkaro.com/search?st=monitor+&loc=hyderabad

For example: https://www.sabrentkaro.com/rental/rent/786  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180821154720/https://www.sabrentkaro.com/rental/rent/786))

[image]

They seem to have some pretty bad online reviews though ([Google Reviews](https://www.google.com/search?q=sabrentkaro&oq=sabrentkaro&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j0l2.326j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#lrd=0x3bcb93ddadd5666d:0xf0ccf2082b1e1735,1,,,),  [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/sabrentkaro/)), but it worked fine for me.

The website asks for a [PAN number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_account_number): you can put a random (but valid) one. The website asks for an Indian phone number to be able receive some OTP to register on their website: somehow the website has some bug and I managed to go through it without having using any Indian phone number (you'll need one though when ordering the monitors so that they can call you when they'll get lost trying to deliver the monitors).

When renting through sabrentkaro.com, the actual provider who came to my place to deliver the monitor seemed to have their own business:

[image]

---

https://www.rentsher.com also rents IT and AV equipment but currently doesn't have any monitor (only laptop, TV, sound speakers or even [LED Display Van](https://www.rentsher.com/product/led-display-van)).